# Best practice: SQL SP serialized execution

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, locking, deadlock

We have an SP, which is executed after a row insertion. It updates several tables in a transaction but in some cases when several rows are inserted and the SP is executed concurrently - it runs into a deadlock. We tried to optimize it, and lowered the chance to end in a deadlock - but cannot avoid it.

Now we tried another way (this SP runs inside a transaction):

```
DECLARE @padLock         INT

BEGIN TRY

EXEC @padLock = sp_getapplock @Resource='mytable_modify', @LockMode='Exclusive', @LockOwner='Transaction';

IF @padLock < 0 
   THROW 99888, 'Lock named [mytable_modify] cannot be acquired.', 1

...
do some stuff which might cause deadlock
...
EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'mytable_modify', @LockOwner='Transaction';

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   SELECT 
       @strErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE() + 
                       'Line:' + CONVERT(varchar(5), ERROR_LINE()),
       @intErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
       @intErrState = ERROR_STATE();

  if @padLock >= 0  
    EXEC sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'mytable_modify', @LockOwner='Transaction';

    RAISERROR(@strErrMsg,   -- Message text.
                @intErrSeverity,  -- Severity.
                @intErrState      -- State
                );
END CATCH;
```

Is it good practice, or are we still in trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Acquiring a course-grained lock (using `sp_getapplock` here) will avoid deadlocks but at the expense of concurrency and throughput.

I wouldn't go so far as to call it a good practice but I've found `sp_getapplock` is an acceptable solution in specialized cases where deadlocks cannot otherwise be avoided easily and the resultant single-threaded performance is acceptable for your workload. If "do some stuff" takes a few milliseconds there's probably no performance concern unless you need to sustain a rate of hundreds per second.

Comment: I won't say it as a "practice" also, and we replaced deadlock situation to timeout situation. The main difference is that the sp_getapplock has a timeout parameter, so without changing the caller side we can wait some time on the DB side.

Comment: Long-running transactions are especially problematic because serializing access will reduce throughput more noticeably, and in your case, to the point of causing timeouts. Perhaps more query/index tuning can mitigate that.